# Contact manager with c program by using structure

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, system, structure, contacts

```
       struct contact
       {
       char name[20],email[20];
       int hpnum;
       }add;
   int option;

       int main (void)
       {
    system("cls");
    printf("==========Welcome to Jeffery's Contact System Management==========\n");
    printf("\t\t\tContact System Main Menu\n");
    printf("[1] Create a New Contact\n");
    printf("[2] Modified Existing Contact\n");
    printf("[3] Delete Existing Contact\n");
    printf("[4] Search Existing Contact\n");
    printf("[5] Exit\n");
    printf("Please enter one of your option.\n");
    scanf("%d",option);

    switch(option)
    {
        //add new contact
        case 1:
        printf("Contact Name: ");
        scanf("%s",&add.name);
        printf("\nHandphone Number: ");
        scanf("%d",&add.hpnum);
        printf("\nE-mail: ");
        scanf("%s",add.email);
        break;
    }

getch();
    }
```

What's the problem of this coding? I can run it, but once choose no. 1, there haven an error. If my coding is wrong, please inform me. I still a beginner, hope you all can help me in this.

Comment: The error is i left an ampersand of scanf("%d",option);
it should be scanf("%d",&option);

another problem is the string...
it should not be scanf("%s",&add.name); instead of scanf("%s",add.name);
because it was a string, so cannot use ampersand in the scanf...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `ampersand &` before *option* variable.

```
 scanf("%d",option);
```

should be

```
 scanf("%d",&option);
```

option is an int, so here need `&` in scanf.

**second:** ampersand  need to remove before *add.name*

```
 scanf("%s",&add.name)
```

should be

```
 scanf("%s",add.name)
```

*add.name* is a char array we don't need `&` with `%s`

Comment: Thanks for the answer...now i having another problem...i changed the code...but there's some problem...can you help me check?
Here's the link...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122225/contact-manager-with-c-program-by-using-structure-different-code

Answer (score 0):

Add a `fflush(stdout);` between these two statements:

```
    printf("Contact Name: ");
    scanf("%s",&add.name);
```

Same with your other `printf` statements that don't end with a `\n` character.

And for information `s` conversion specifier expects a pointer to `char` so don't use the `&` operator and just call `scanf("%s", add.name)`.