# Contact manager with c program by using structure different code

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, system, structure, contacts

Now I having another problem with that, after I changed my coding as shown below, it still showing out the error. Inside the coding, there was no any red underline, therefore I can't find out where's the error. So any error of this coding?

```
struct contact
{
    char name[20],email[20];
    int hpnum;
}add;
int option;
FILE *f;

void addcontact(struct contact list[100]);
void read(struct contact list[100]);

int main (void)
{
    struct contact list[100];
    system("cls");
    printf("==========Welcome to Jeffery's Contact System Management==========\n");
    printf("\t\t\tContact System Main Menu\n");
    printf("[1] Create a New Contact\n");
    printf("[2] Modified Existing Contact\n");
    printf("[3] Delete Existing Contact\n");
    printf("[4] Search Existing Contact\n");
    printf("[5] Exit\n");
    printf("Please enter one of your option.\n");
    scanf("%d",&option);
    switch(option)
    {
        //add new contact
        case 1:addcontact(list);read(list);
        break;
    }

    getch();
}

void addcontact(struct contact list[100])
{
    char name[20],email[20];
    int hpnum,no;

    printf("\nContact Name: ");
    scanf("%s",list[no-1].name);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nHandphone Number: ");
    scanf("%d",&list[no-1].hpnum);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nE-mail: ");
    scanf("%s",list[no-1].email);
}

void read(struct contact list[100])
{
  FILE *f;
  f=fopen("contact.txt","w");
  fwrite(list,sizeof(list),100,f);
  fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "it still showing out the error" means?

Comment: When i running the problem, there will be no error, once I choose the 1st to add contact, there will be an error came out...the error is Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'no' is being used without being initialized.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Answer (score 0):

**First,** `fflush(stdin);` is [undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin) error. should use `fflush(stdout);`

**Second,** in function `addcontact(struct contact list[100])` variable *no* has not assigned any value and you are using in `scanf()` function with garbage value.

**Third**, in `read()` function `fwrite(list,sizeof(list),100,f);` is wrong it should be like.

```
fwrite(list, sizeof(struct contact), 100, f);
```

<sub>I am not sure but it looks You are intended to read more then one contacts So you also need a looping mechanism probably inside addcontact() function</sub>

Comment: I changed to stdout and i already initial the value of no equal to zero. I can finish my problem...now the problem is after i type all the information, the txt file does execute. But inside the txt file, it does not show any information.

Comment: If you initialize no to zero then `list[no-1]` become buggy because `no-1` would be `-1`. You need to give +ve value to no...

Comment: Yes. There is no bug now. But now the problem is after the txt file executed, inside the txt file has no my contact information.

Comment: @LeoJieHui updated answer. Try again & in `addcontact()` write `list[no]` when `no` should be a valid +ve value.

Comment: Erm...it's still the same happened in the txt file. The txt file doesn't consist the thing that what i typed in cmd. It just displaying the word that are weird.

Comment: @LeoJieHui Why do you trying with full data 100...first try with 3-4 list size. enter statically all record manually in list in code. then step-by-step improve your code.

Comment: Hmm...then I try to change a bit of coding now and see. Anyway, thanks for you instructions. =)